# Python Threading. Нужен ли локер на данные доступные разным трэдам?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Стоит задача организовать переменную состояния, в которую один трэд пишет, другой читает. Господа сишники сразу указали на необходимость существования лока при записи, чтении в переменную состояния. Не поверил. Пробую:

```
import thread
status = ''

def first():
    global status
    mes = ['0000000000','1111111111']
    while 1:
        status = mes[0]
        status = mes[1]

def second():
    mes = ['0000000000','1111111111']
    while 1:
        if status not in mes:
            print('Ahtung!!!!!')

thread.start_new_thread(first,())
thread.start_new_thread(second,())
```

До сих пор бежит без конфликтов.
Кто же прав? Разруливает ли эту ситуацию python или модуль thread?
P.S. Естественно, я представляю себе что такое потоки и что подобная проблема должна существовать...

Comment: >До сих пор бежит без конфликтов.

А какие конфликты Вы ожидали здесь увидеть?

Comment: Первый поток успеет записать только '11', так как начнет выполняться второй поток. Следовательно стринга будет не полная.
Это все от лукавого C.

Comment: Тогда лучше попробовать 100 (или 1000) потоков, а не 2. 1 пусть пишет, а 99 проверяют вхождение.

Comment: Почитал про GIL. Желание проверять отпало сам собой...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле в питоне существует такая вещь, как GIL, глобальная блокировка интерпретатора. Чтобы поток мог выполнять операции, нужно захватить GIL, поэтому  в один момент времени не может выполняться более одного потока. Правда я пока не особо понимаю в какой момент GIL может быть перехвачен, но скорее всего все стандартные структуры данных задизайнены так, чтобы быть консистентными при использовании такой блокировки. Подробнее смотри [здесь](http://www.seobuilding.ru/wiki/Python#.D0.93.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B0_.28GIL.29)

Comment: Спасибо, ключевое слово - GIL.